# sql alias field

Tags: sql, mysql, column-alias

in SQL, supposes I need to refer to an aliased field in the having clause but the alias has quotes, how do I do that?

```
select (select...) as '005'
group by ...
having '005'>0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a FROM clause, and you should use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
SELECT (SELECT ...) AS `005`
FROM table1
GROUP BY ...
HAVING `005` > 0
```

It would help if you posted your full query, as I am guessing a bit here as to what you want to do.

Comment: As Mark said the problem is that you are using single quotes rather than back ticks, which makes the alias be treated as a string literal. In the select portion the alias can use normal quotes, but anywhere else it is used you need to use the back ticks.

Comment: You guys are right, if I use Backticks instead of single quotes the alias works!, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The SQL-92 standard defines using double quotes for a column alias, rather than single quotes.  In most databases, unusual characters are only allowed if you use double quotes.

That said, not all databases support referring to a column alias (in the same query) in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses.  For portable queries, I don't recommend the practice of referring to a column alias in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses.  Additionally, the `HAVING` clause is for aggregates - the simplified example you provided should trigger an error because no aggregate function (IE: COUNT, AVG, MIN/MAX, etc) is performed on the `005` column alias.

The following works for me on MySQL 4.1:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS "005"
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY ...
  HAVING `005` > 0
```